# Conceptual questions about Galilean relativity

Tags: classical-mechanics, inertial-frames, observers, galilean-relativity

I want to see if Galilean relativity is as mind-blowing as a think it is.

I'm imagining two individuals each on their own planets. Ignore gravity for now, they are attached to the planets, and there is nothing else in the sky but the two planets. Each observer feels nothing and each observer sees the other planet coming toward them, growing larger and larger. They slowly come together over time then stop "instantly" when they touch. A saw B approaching her and B saw A approaching him. Neither felt like they moved.

A and B could argue and argue and never know which one was moving, or which one was moving faster (again saying they stopped "instantly"). But a third observer C *would* know the real story. They could have moved equally or unequally fast, or one could have been still. But A and B can't know which until confirming with C or having other objects in the sky.

*Is this essentially Galilean relativity?*

*This is incompatible with absolute time and space right? Did Newton know this and did he formulate his theories anyway?*

*So already A and B (without invoking C at all) would know the mental image of absolute time and space we all have in our heads must be wrong, just from them observing and feeling what they did and upon discussing each's story?*

*Edit: As said by two commenters, I can't say C would know the real story. Can I even say C would know a better story? Does C have just as nebulous of a story of "what actually" happened?*

Comment: Would observer C really know the true story, if C is actually co-moving with A or B? Do they have to ask another inertial observer D?

Comment: You can't say that $C$ is at rest. It might happen that $C$ is moving half the velocity of $B$ then its observation will be different from that of another frame $D$ which might be moving with the velocity half of that of $A$. So there is nothing called absolute rest.

Comment: @jamie1989 "@Iti" seems I that went right over my head. I shouldn't have said "real story" Can I say a better story? Or is no story better than another? Just relative to it?

Comment: No story better than another.

Comment: " _So already A and B (without invoking C at all) would know the mental image of absolute time and space we all have in our heads must be wrong_ " Absolute time is not wrong in Galilean relativity

Comment: @silverrahul Ty, just absolute space?